# Zip and remove folder to reduce a Docker layer of a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Considering I have a huge Docker Image and that I don't have the time to dig into all the best Docker pratices for image reduction techniques and that I am aware of the specifically huge part of the Docker image.

I wanted to zip the huge folder, delete original folder and simply unzip the folder when the image boot.

```
...
RUN cd /mypath/ && <COMMAND_THAT_GENERATE_HUGE_DIR_BOB> && zip -r bob.zip bob &&  rm -rd bob
...
```

In some way this is working since my **bob.zip** is about 60% of the **original bob dir**. However, probably due to the way Docker handles layer in the background. Even tough **bob.zip** is smaller, the docker layer appears to be:

(**bob.zip** size) + (**original bob dir** size)

instead of simply:`

(**bob.zip** size)

Is there a flag or something I can use to get the expected layer size?

Comment: I'd guess that this is because docker creates a separate layer for the `COPY` step, thus adding the whole content as additional size to the zipped version

Comment: In that case I guess multi-stage build might be the solution here. I will try to follow https://towardsdatascience.com/using-multi-stage-builds-to-make-your-docker-image-almost-10x-smaller-239068cb6fb0

Comment: Actually, check out [this article](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2020/04/docker-images-part3-going-farther-reduce-image-size.html#compression-a-bad-good-idea).
Docker images are already compressed by default, so zipping it probably won't give you too much of a benefit.

Additionally, when size matters, try using alpine as the base. It depends on the language that you're writing it in (if you're compiling to native, the musl base can be an issue), but it's worth a try at least.

Comment: An Alpine-based image will be marginally smaller but can come with various compatibility concerns as well.  If you're worrying about a data set that's hundreds of megabytes, you won't notice the difference between an Alpine or Debian base, and if you start from Alpine but then add back the GNU command-line tools and C library then you haven't actually saved space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Dockerfile `RUN` line *always* makes the image larger.  A Docker image is built from *layers*, and what a `RUN` line does is start from a previous layer, run a command, and remember the filesystem changes as a new layer.  As an extreme example, `RUN rm -rf /` will actually result in an image somewhat larger than the preceding step, even though there are no files left in the image.

You hint at a multi-stage build and that's one valid approach here.  The important thing is to compress the data in a separate stage from the final runtime stage:

```bash
FROM ubuntu AS data
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN ./command_that_generate_huge_dir_bob
RUN zip -r bob.zip bob  # I might use `tar czf bob.tar.gz bob`

FROM ...
...
COPY --from=data /app/bob.zip ./
...
```

The important detail here is that the uncompressed data never actually exists in the final image; you're only copying in the zipped file.

The approach you show in the question of generating the data, compressing it, and then deleting the raw data all inside a single `RUN` command should work as well, though it can be a little more finicky.

If you do `COPY` in the entire host directory tree (as I've done in this example) one thing to check is that this isn't accidentally including a copy of the uncompressed data.  You can include the data directory in a `.dockerignore` file to ensure this.

If this data really is static data, one other option is to supply it to the container at run time.  I've used this approach in the past with a very large NLP model that simply didn't fit in an image.  This makes distributing and deploying the application more complex, but it does make the image size more reasonable (I've found a practical limit for an image is about 1 GB, otherwise things like `docker pull` start spontaneously failing).  Make sure your image doesn't contain the data directory at all, then bind-mount it when you run the container

```bash
# on the host
./command_that_generate_huge_dir_bob
docker run ... -v "$PWD/bob:/app/bob" ...
```

Comment: Thx really interesting! Will test a few things based on that and probably accept your answer depending on how well I can put it in place and if no other answers match this one.

Comment: Finally I did multi single stage which was easier to handle on my side where on the final stage I place my zip from a previous stage. I will accept this answer since it is close enough.